# getClassLoader().getResource() returns null

Tags: java, applet

I have this test app:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
public class Test extends Applet
{

    public void init()
    {
        URL some=Test.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/assets/pacman.png");
        System.out.println(some.toString());
        System.out.println(some.getFile());
        System.out.println(some.getPath());

    }
}
```

When I run it from Eclipse, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.init(Test.java:9)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Classpath (from .CLASSPATH file)

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
```

In my c:\project\src folder, I have only the Test.java file and the 'assets' directory which contains pacman.png.

What am I doing wrong and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
final InputStream stream;

stream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("assets/pacman.png");
System.out.println("Stream = " + stream);
```

"/assets/pacman.png" is an absolute location whle "assets/pacman.png" is a relative location.

Comment: as expected, given that you other attempts didn't work.  What is the package that the classes are in, where is the .class file located?

Comment: The .class is put in c:\java\test\bin when i hit run in eclipse. The .java is in c:\java\test\src and the assets/ folder is also in this dir. No package being used right now because im just trying to make it work for my other project. Thanks

Comment: the assests dir needs to be where the .class file is

Answer (score 23):

You don't need the slash at the start when getting a resource from a `ClassLoader`, because there's no idea of a "relative" part to start with. You only need it when you're getting a resource from a `Class` where relative paths go from the class's package level.

In addition, you don't want `Test.class.getClass()` as that gets the class *of* Test.class, which will be `Class<Class>`.

In other words, try either of these lines:

```
URL viaClass=Test.class.getResource("/assets/pacman.png");
URL viaLoader=Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("assets/pacman.png");
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both but it doesn't work, however now it gives an exception on line 10 (which is the first system.out.println line) instead of line 9. I've made sure and the image is in project/src/assets...

Comment: that measn that "some" is null... which means you are not getting the resource properly.

Comment: yes, so how can i resolve it? is the classpath incorrect or something else i need to change?

Comment: Try getting the applet side of things out of the equation - run the same code in a console app.

Comment: But i'm building an applet so I could run this in a web browser, it would be pointless to make it a console :(. There must be some way to make it work in the applet? How do applets use images?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be pointless to make it a console app - it would solve one problem at a time. Make sure you can get a resource in a simple setting, then move on to a more complicated one. For instance, your original code would have failed even in a console app.

Comment: Ok, i removed all references to applet and changed init method to public static void main(String args[]). Got the error : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Test.main(Test.java:10)"

Comment: Same output for both of your examples

Comment: Glad you've got this fixed now. The technique of "use a simpler context to check something" is an important one though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Given that someone uses an absolute path to the resource - then it should not matter whether it is loaded via class.getResource or class.getClassLoader().getResource. Or am I assuming wrongly?

Comment: @Queeg: It's been many years since I looked at this, but I seem to recall that if you *do* specify an "absolute" path in ClassLoader.getResource, the lookup would fail. Of course, I may be misremembering - or things may well have changed in the last 13 years.

Answer (score 8):

- When you use `.getClass().getResource(fileName)` it considers the
  location of the fileName is the same location of the of the calling
  class.
- When you use `.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)` it
  considers the location of the fileName is the root - in other words
  bin folder

It hits `NullPointerException` if the file is actually not exist there.

Source:

```
package Sound;
public class ResourceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "Kalimba.mp3";
        System.out.println(fileName);
        System.out.println(new ResourceTest().getClass().getResource(fileName));
        System.out.println(new ResourceTest().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName));
```

Output:

```
Kalimba.mp3
file:/C:/Users/User/Workspaces/MyEclipse%208.5/JMplayer/bin/Sound/Kalimba.mp3
file:/C:/Users/User/Workspaces/MyEclipse%208.5/JMplayer/bin/Kalimba.mp3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

> URL viaClass=Test.class.getResource("assets/test.html");

which assets in the same folder with Test.class output file (after a miserable checking and debugging)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the 'resouces' file is a normal file type

[image]

Then my code worked

URL url = FileUtility.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.json");