# How do I access a JPG embedded in my JAR file via a URL object? What would be the address?

Tags: java, url, jar

I've bundled a JPG inside of my application's JAR file.  I need to access it, preferably via a URL object from the code in the same JAR.  But I've no idea how to construct the address.  I'm guessing it would be a "file:///" but what comes after that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625687/java-getclassloader-getresource-driving-me-bonkers

Comment: It would only be a duplicate if I knew that ClassLoader or getResource had anything to do with it.  Its content did help, as the comments below did, but I was needing the basis of the method vs. that question needing implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ClassLoader.getResource`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), specifying a slash-delimited resource path.

Comment: ...wherein you pass the JAR-relative path.

Comment: also save yourself potential headaches and use 'absolute classpath paths', ie paths that start with a '/'. Otherwise the path is relative to the class that is calling the code, and can run into problems if the class is part of an inheritance hierarchy that spans packages.

Comment: not true - this answer states ClassLoader.getReosurce, which always treats resource names as relatve to the classpath root.