# File reading applet not running in browser

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

My java database applet program read the file from their current directory like
`FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("details.txt");`

When I run through appletviewer, it works but through browser, it doesn't showing any output.
error :

`Error: details.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I put this file in same directory.

My applet tag is :

`<applet code="hack.database.MyApplet.class" archive="MyApplet.jar, ojdbc14.jar" height="800" width="1000">
</applet>`

Comment: Please tell us what do you mean by "in same directory". (I think your answer to this should pretty much lead you to the answer to this question.)

Comment: The folder in which all classes and jar files are present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally you can't use a `FileInputStream` for this, `FileInputStream` is for reading *files*, and you can't access the local file system in an unsigned applet. Your resources are available over the net, not as files. If your applet **is** signed, the code you've quoted will look for the "details.txt" file in the user's current *working* directory in their file system, not necessarily the directory containing the class file.

You can load resources from within the jar the applet class is in using [`Class#getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get a `URL` you can open, or using [`Class#getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to do it all in one. So for instance, this code within an instance method within an applet will open an `InputStream` to the "details.txt" file in the same directory in the jar as the applet `class` file:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("details.txt");
```

I know that works for resources within the jar. Whether it works for other resources on the same codebase I couldn't say, I always bundle everything into the jar. See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625687/java-getclassloader-getresource-driving-me-bonkers) (and its answers).

So two steps: Put the file in the jar, and use the code above to retrieve its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` class method to obtain `InputStream`. Unsigned Applets cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem. For more information read - [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

Comment: My applet is already signed. It can run through appletviewer.