# java getResource() not working

Tags: java, url, embedded-resource

this is driving me crazy.
I have a NetBeans project in a folder with the following structure:

```
MyProject
---- build
---- src
---- resources
```

in src my code is in packages. What I am trying to do is to use

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/new.png");
```

from a class in package com.my.package but it just refuses to work! The "new.png" image is in the resources folder.
Am I missing something here?

After a lot of playing around and moving the "new.png" image here and there to see when it will find the image, it finally worked but only when I put the image in the build folder.
So what do I have to do to make this work ?

edit: sorry, wrong String in method parameter. Corrected now

Comment: But where do you tell the method that the image is in the resources folder? (not my down-vote). Note that resources are found relative to the class loader's path.

Comment: The `resources` folder needs to end up on the classpath; do you have it listed as a source folder? Is it being included at the root level in the jar? Etc--without knowing more it's difficult to be more helpful.

Comment: not entirely familiar with what you are saying. How do I list something as a source folder? The thing is that even when my image is not in the folder, but just in the root of my project it still won't find it with getClass().getResource("/test.png");

Comment: The root of your project is probably not on the classpath, so the .png is invisible as far as the classloader is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NetBeans, but the problem is probably that the `resources` folder (or the root of the project, for that matter) is not on the classpath, unlike `build`.

You need to configure NetBeans to add the root folder, or `resources` to the classpath, and load the file relative to there.

See also this question: [Java - getClassLoader().getResource() driving me bonkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625687/java-getclassloader-getresource-driving-me-bonkers/625712)

Comment: That is indeed the reason why. I was under the impression that this is automatically done and I never had this happen in the past. Now I only have to figure out how to add my root in my classpath for a NetBeans project :D

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file_name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

look out with `ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file_name"));`

...on windows you will get a URL encoded string, with %20 for spaces, so if you want to use that path to load a file, first call pathString.replace("%20", " ")  ...that $hice just nailed me in live!