# load an image from project's folder in java

Tags: java, io

I want to load an image which is in my projet folder as : `/src/images/URL.jpg`

I tried this code :

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/URL.jpg"));
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at Personel.PersonnelMainForm.print(PersonnelMainForm.java:464)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Show more code please. Is your image where you believe it is in your running classpath? Try and see if your `.getResource()` returns null, this is what I believe happens here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) version of `read`, which takes File as an argument.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("path"));
```

where `path` is the path to you file, absolute or relative as you need.

Another option, if you really want to load it as a resource, would be editing your classpath, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440035/java-getresource-not-working).

Comment: This is not a practical approach for deployment.  Put the resource in a Jar and access it as an [tag:embedded-resource].

Answer (score 4):

From personal experience I use:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg"));
```

I get the resource as a stream and that seems to work fine for me.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me and it's very short code!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a java class in the package. 
You have to move up so many times as package levels. 
Example:
Java class is defined as org.test.MyClass
you have to go up twice (../../) to be in the main directory.