# Why relative path doesn't work in JAVA in JAR-file?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple JavaFX project. It consists from:

- src/app/Main.java
- src/app/controller/MainController.java
- src/app/controller/SecondaryWindowController.java
- src/app/view/Main.fxml
- src/app/view/SecondaryWindow.fxml

The controller **MainController.java** has method (handler of press button):

```
public void openWindow(ActionEvent event) {
    Pane root = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("URL: " + getClass().getResource("../view/SecondaryWindow.fxml"));
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../view/SecondaryWindow.fxml") );
        root = loader.load();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (root != null) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,100);
        Stage secStage = new Stage();
        secStage.setTitle("Secondary Window");
        secStage.setScene(scene);
        secStage.show();
    }
}
```

Code **getClass().getResource("../view/SecondaryWindow.fxml")** return right URL if I run project from compile files. But it return **null** if I run project from JAR-file.

I compile files using:

```
javac -d bin src\app\Main.java
javac -d bin src\app\controller\*.java
XCOPY src\app\view\*.fxml bin\app\view /s /e /d /y
```

and run compile files using:

```
java -classpath bin app.Main
```

Catalog **bin** has similar structure of files:

- bin/app/Main.class
- bin/app/controller/MainController.class
- bin/app/controller/SecondaryWindowController.class
- bin/app/view/Main.fxml
- bin/app/view/SecondaryWindow.fxml

And I create JAR-file using:

```
jar cvfm SimpleFXMLApp.jar manifest.mf -C bin app
```

Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Denys Selivanov
Main-Class: app.Main
```

Why relative path doesn't work in **JAR-file** and **getClass().getResource("../view/SecondaryWindow.fxml")** return **null** ?
How repair that?

One of the problem's solves is keep controllers and views files in one catalog and use relative path "SecondaryWindows.fxml", but I want keep my structure files of project.

And you can download my project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzvxWG8M62OWZHQySzA5WXk3YTQ). This link will be access 30 days.

Comment: Because a JAR file is not a file system, and `..` is for file systems. Some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I see the vote to close that says it's a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440035/java-getresource-not-working), but I don't think it explains the specifics of `..`, so here you go:</sub>

`..` works on resources on the filesystem, because `..` is an actual entry on the filesystem, that points to parent directory. But that does not exist within jars, so it won't work to point to "parent package" when your classes & resources are packaged in a jar.

Solution: if you can accept the dependency from your controller class to `Main` class, you can do this instead:

```
Main.class.getResource("view/SecondaryWindow.fxml")
```

In any case you'll need to either reference a class that is high enough in the packages hierarchy, or use an absolute path from root package (`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("app/view/SecondaryWindow.fxml")` in your case apparently).

Comment: Both variants (relative path from highest class and absolute path from root package) work. But getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(/app/view/SecondaryWindow.fxml)  don't work, instead I use getClass().getResource(/app/view/SecondaryWindow.fxml).   Thank you.

Comment: Ah, yes in last example there was a mistake, I edited to fix

Comment: Oh, the [new duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755630/javafx-location-is-not-set-error) has a better answer than the original I mentioned, it explains why `..` does not work here.