# NullPointerException in a Java Applet accessing an image

Tags: java, applet

I'm attempting to load an image from inside my Java Applet. I'm receiving a null pointer error. I'm using [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373021/how-to-includes-all-images-in-jar-file-using-eclipse) as a guide for my code however it is not working as expected. Below are two images of my packages and how they appear inside my JAR.

[image: Packages]
[image: Jar Contents]

The specific code I am using the load the image is as below:

```
ImageIcon logoIco = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png"));
```

This specific code is being run in the Director class however all the other code in that class works. I know it is the image because if I comment out the line and just make the image null the program works as expected.

I can confirm the image works just fine if I load it as an application or via the command line it does however not work at all inside any web browser I have tested it on. As I am running this locally I have made an exception in my Java security to ensure this isn't an issue and will then test it on default settings once I can get it working.

Why is this not loading?

Comment: Can you try `./images/logo.png`? I am not tryed it, but I think the absolute path may be the problem.

Comment: ./images/logo.png still errors out and then also causes an error via command line which was not occurring before.

Comment: Do you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625687/java-getclassloader-getresource-driving-me-bonkers ?

Comment: Tried every combination in that thread still no dice.